# Flutter project run on the ios13

Tags: ios, flutter

I just update my system to the latest MacOS 10.15 , and Xcode update to 11 , my iPhone XR just update to the iOS 13.1 . I run my flutter project, then get error here

the log

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/eriklu/development/codes/flutter/study/flutter_trip/demo/flutter_base_demo/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework':
    1) Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/eriklu/development/codes/flutter/study/flutter_trip/demo/flutter_base_demo/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework' to '/Users/eriklu/development/codes/flutter/study/flutter_trip/demo/flutter_base_demo/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
    2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build descriptionwarning: duplicate output file '/Users/eriklu/development/codes/flutter/study/flutter_trip/demo/flutter_base_demo/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks /Users/eriklu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cguezvpzlkcjmwafakhebgbckazf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-73506C6A4A6DF54A6CA02CB5.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on 路过的程序猿.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Xcode and go to the **Runner**'s settings and open the **Build Phases** tab.
Go to Embed Frameworks, you should definitely see **Flutter.framework** and **App.Framework**

[Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meGel.png)

Check that actually during the update Xcode has not damaged the files in the Framework, you can usually see it by looking at the icon, but you can also use the right button and see it in the Finder.

If you should see the disabled icon or could not open it in the Finder the solution is quite simple, you just need to create a new application in Flutter and replace the Framework folders (for iOS) that are in

*yourAppName / **ios** / **Flutter** /*